# Flex get error messages in production mode too

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, error-handling, flex4.6

I am building an application in Flex 4.6 which load a lot of stuff at the runtime. This stuff will be placed by the end users. Between all these files, there is an handwritten xml file.

In this case, it could be possible that the file is invalid (closing tag different from the opening tag, etc...). If there is a problem, Flex raise an error which can be catched.

Actually, I display the error message in a popup and everything work fine... only in the IDE (Flash Builder 4.6).
When I build and install a release to test, I get the error ID instead of the error message.

How is it possible ?

Here is the code I use.

```
private function loadXML(file:ByteArray = null):void
{
    if(file){
        try{
            // Parse the xml file
            var data:XML = new XML(file.toString());

            ... some code ...

        }catch(e:Error){
            Alert.show("Cannot parse the xml file. " + e.message);
        }
    }else{
        Alert.show("No xml file.");
    }
}
```

Here is what I get inside the ide (both debug and release mode):

```
Cannot parse the xml file. Error #1085: The element type "textc" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</textc>".
```

And here is what I get with the release build:

```
Cannot parse the xml file. Error #1085
```

Why did the message change in a release build and how can I keep this message ?

Comment: In a debug build the complete symbolic debug information is kept to help while debugging applications and also the code optimization is not taken into account. 

This is why you don't have access to stack traces in a release build.

On this specific situation I don't see why you shouldn't see the error description. Being flex I can only assume this is a bug itself.

Comment: In this case, the only thing I can do is inform the user that there could be an error, somewhere in the xml. But it will not really help to find it... Thank you anyway.

Comment: I don't think its a Flex bug. The string in `e.message` is just different in the release build, right? Is the error thrown by the code that instantiates the XML object: `var data:XML = new XML(file.toString())` That's a native Flash Player class, nothing to do with Flex ;)  You might look at using a 3rd party lib to validate the XML before you run the offending code, but I wouldn't know if such an API exists...

Comment: I had the same idea, but there is also another problem with using another parser after that. In fact, this xml will be **really** huge. Actually, launching the application is already slow because of the size of the xml. If, after spending this loading time, I add another time to parse one more time the xml, it will be really too much. Actually, I have decided to inform the user that there is an error somewhere and ask to use an xml validator to find it. But thank you anyway.